# Macro that replaces all calls to printf with nothing

Tags: c++, macros

I want to create a macro that replaces all calls to `printf`, more specifically `mbedtls_printf` (which behaves the exact sameway as `printf`) with nothing.

I know I can use `#define mbedtls_printf` to replace `mbedtls_printf` with nothing, but this will still leave the parameters/parenthesis intact.

Edit - I forgot to mention that `mbedtls_printf` is a macro that replaces itself with `sgx_printf`

Comment: do you want the arguments evaluated or not?

Comment: `printf("%d\n", DoSomethingImportant())` - do you want the inner function to be evaluated?

Comment: You can’t do this with code that uses the value that `printf` returns.

Comment: I know that the arguments will never be evaluated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know I can use #define mbedtls_printf to replace mbedtls_printf with nothing, but this will still leave the parameters/parenthesis intact.

It's OK if the argument list remains, because then it will be treated as an expression. If we have an expression and we do nothing to it, then it will just be optimized out (on any decent compiler). Consider [the following](http://codepad.org/oY5Y7h5m):

```
int x(char a, double b)
{
    return printf("%c %f\n", a, b);
}

#define x 

int main(void)
{
    x('P', 3.14);
}
```

The compiler sees the following code for `main`:

```
('P', 3.14);
```

This expression evaluates to 3.14 (the comma operator returns its right-hand operand). Such an expression is quietly optimized.

Answer (score 3):

The following works, at least with gcc 8. A brief search suggests that variadic macros were introduced with C99:

```
#define printf(...) do { } while (0)

int main()
{
    printf("Hello %s?\n", "world");
    return 0;
}
```

You want to use the ol' "do {} while (0)" trick, in order to avoid surprises like:

```
if (something)
    printf("Something else");

will_this_be_invoked_or_not();
```

You can't make `printf()` disappear completely. Because this would make the next line a logical part of the preceding `if` statement. Hillarity ensues. That's why you still have to leave something in place.

Comment: You can even change it to just `#define printf(...) do { } while (0)` (no `;`).

Comment: This is wrong and will break valid code. Try `#define printf(...) ((void)0)` (note no semicolon).

Answer (score 3):

I would go with:

```
#define printf(...) (0)
```

The benefit here is that it will continue to compile in cases where someone actually bothers to check the return from printf (rare but not unheard of).

Comment: If anyone writes such check, it is likely to be `printf(whatever)>0` so it will fail.

Comment: @n.m.: 0 characters is printed, So it is a "correct" implementation ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If you completely no-op out the printf statements, there may be a bug lurking.  Consider the following code:

```
printf("Result is %d\n", DoSomethingVeryImportant());
```

When you replace the printf call with a macro, you likely still want to make sure the inner function call to `DoSomethingVeryImportant()` is invoked.  Otherwise, you've changed the logic of your program.

And I suppose you might want to have your mbedtls_printf actually call printf for debug builds, but be a no-op in a retail build.

If all of the above is of value, consider this as mbedtls_printf.h:

```
#ifndef MBEDTLS_PRINTF_H
#define MBEDTLS_PRINTF_H

#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef DEBUG_BUILD
inline int printf_stub(const char* s, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, s);
    vprintf(s, args);
    va_end(args);
}

#define mbedtls_printf(...) printf_stub(__VA_ARGS__)

#else
inline int printf_stub(...){return 1;}
#define mbedtls_printf(...) printf_stub(__VA_ARGS__)
#endif

#endif
```

Then in code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mbedtls_printf.h"

int ImportantFunction()
{
   std::cout << "Really important code" << std::endl;
   return 42;
}

int main()
{
    mbedtls_printf("Result of a very important step: %d\n", ImportantFunction());
    mbedtls_printf("This just happened");
    mbedtls_printf("Result of a another important step: ", 43, 44, ImportantFunction());
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler will optimize out the empty function call and still invoke `ImportantFunction()` as it was doing originally.

Comment: `va_start` and `va_end` aren't defined

Comment: @Roymunson - You will need to `#include <stdarg.h>` everywhere it's needed. I've touched the code above to help.  But if you really want to **learn** C and C++, digging in and fixing compiler (and linker) issues are good exercises.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda): (*[Variadic macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html) since [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99)*)

```
#define printf(...) []{}()
```

What this does is simply replace the `printf()` calls to `[]{}()`... This just means an empty function call... which can be formatted to be like this:

```
#define printf(...) [] { \
                       }()
```

*Or, even this suffices:*

```
// Replacing printf() with an empty function that just takes variadic arguments
#define printf [](...){}
```

**Edit:** You *can* also use:

```
#define printf void(0)
```

Comment: A *do-nothing void expression* can be written in plain old C without all this newfangled lambda stuff.

Comment: The second version will still evaluate arguments, which is probably unwanted.